# Define hashtag variable in ngFor

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am trying to implement an ngFor loop to show multiple charts. Its number will be variable so I wanted to use a loop to create all of them depending on the amount of arrays received as parameter:

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let canvas of canvasList">
    <ion-card-header class="backheader">
      Position {{canvas.position}}
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <canvas #name_{{canvas.position}}</canvas>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

but I am getting an error related to my use of #name_X

What is the correct way to do this? Also, I don't know how I should handle this:

```
@ViewChild('sensor0Canvas') sensor0Canvas;
```

and this:

```
this.sensor0Canvas.nativeElement...
```

In my class, I will not need 0,1,2,3.... fixed, it should be variable too. Is this posible? Should I try another aproach?

Comment: If you have multiple items, don't you want `@ViewChildren`? You can't dynamically generate template reference variables, as far as I'm aware, but you could select them by e.g. class.

Comment: Actually, I don't know if I need ViewChildren or not. I am beginner with ionic and angular. I will try with classes and if I am not able to do it, I will leave with a fixed number of charts. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'll prefer you to create a separate component for your canvas and then you will get that using `@ViewChildren` and `QueryList`.

```
@Component({
 selector: 'my-canvas',
 template: '<canvas></canvas>'
})
export class MyCanvasComponent {
 // do handle your canvas element here
}
```

And in you loop

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-card *ngFor="let canvas of canvasList">
    <ion-card-header class="backheader">
      Position {{canvas.position}}
    </ion-card-header>
    <ion-card-content>
      <my-canvas></my-canvas>
    </ion-card-content>
  </ion-card>
</ion-list>
```

and get all canvas through

```
 @ViewChildren(MyCanvasComponent) canvases: QueryList<MyCanvasComponent>;
```

It will return a array of all your canvas components then you can directly call their methods inputs etc from here. Good luck.